# why this not worked in asp.net MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a project who i migrate to MVC 3 from 2.

if i write same in fresh MVc 3 project that they are work fine with but my migrated project not worked for this code

```
 <select id="selrecipetype">
                            @foreach (custom.Type type in rectypes)
                            {
                                <option value="@(type.ID)">@(type.Type)
                                </option>
                            }
                        </select>

Compiler Error Message: CS1525: Invalid expression term ';'
Line 217:                                <option value="@(type.ID)">@(type.Type)
Line 218:                                </option>
Line 219:                            }
Line 220:                        </select>
```

so what is wrong gone happened in this code.

if i write this this same not worked

> @foreach (Categories.Article category in
>   categories)
>                               {
>
> @(category.Name)
>
> }

i want to know why it's not worked and i got error when work fine if  i do in fresh MVC 3 project

Comment: use `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper method instead of manually rendering drop down list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm, such code doesn't have to exist, so why care whether it works or not? Not to mention that this `<select>` doesn't have a name meaning that other than using javascript the selected value will never be posted to the server. So start by simply selecting this code in the IDE and pressing the `Del.` button on your keyboard.

The proper way to generate drop down lists in ASP.NET MVC is using the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SomePropertyOnYourViewModelToBindTheResultTo,
    new SelectList(rectypes, "ID", "Type")
)
```

or if you don't have a strongly typed view (which of course you should, but who knows):

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SomeProperty",
    new SelectList(rectypes, "ID", "Type"),
)
```

Comment: why not worked in migrate same work fine in fresh copy of MVC 3 project

Comment: @Steven Spielberg, that's impossible to tell from the level of details and code you provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should really do your select list using the HTML class. You should first create your select list in the controller like the following:

```
var types = typeRepo.GetRecTypes();
ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(types, "KeyFieldName", "TitleFieldName");
```

then in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectListName", (SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList)
```